# Palindrome for Integers and Strings Java

Tags: java, palindrome

I'm trying to create Palindrome app for Integers and Strings in Java, I'm having an issue with my if statement, it outputs incorrect/repeating True and False statements:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Palindrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter characters to check for Palindrome: ");



        if ( user_input.hasNextInt() ){
            String intToString = String.valueOf(user_input.nextInt()).toString();
            String reversedInt = new StringBuffer(intToString).reverse().toString();

            for (int i = 0; i<intToString.length(); i++) {
                if (intToString.charAt(i) != reversedInt.charAt(i)) { 
                        System.out.println("False");
                    }

                else {
                        System.out.println("True");
                    }
                }
            }


        else if ( user_input.hasNextLine() ) {
            String user_string = user_input.nextLine().replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase();
            StringBuilder user_mutable_string = new StringBuilder(user_string);
            user_mutable_string.reverse();

                if (user_string.equals(user_mutable_string.toString())) {
                    System.out.println("True");
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("False");
                }   
            }

        else {
            System.out.println("Bonkers!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago. Note: you also use StringBuilder.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the for loop, which you don't need. You have already reversed the numbers and converted both the original and reversed numbers to a String. All you need to do then is to compare them. Change the for loop to a simple if:

```
        if (intToString.equals(reversedInt)) { 
            System.out.println("True");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
```

Comment: Haha, that's actually true, didn't notice that at first :D

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a loop to check the *whole* string, you don't want to output `True` immediately, since you don't know yet at that point. It could be, that the next char won't pass the condition. 
You should use a boolean variable instead, like this

```
boolean isPalindrome = true; // let's assume it will be ok
for (int i = 0; i<intToString.length(); i++) {
  if (intToString.charAt(i) != reversedInt.charAt(i)) { 
    isPalindrome = false;
  }
}
System.out.println(isPalindrome);
```